# why my for loop isn't working when I am doing it right?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to execute a loop of factorial in Java script but for some reason, it is not giving the right answer... the same code has been executed in another file before and that code worked without showing any error...

```js
let fact = 1;
let n = 5;
for (let x = 1; x > n; x++) {
  fact *= (x)
}

console.log(fact)
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two issues:

1. You are using `x > n`, but it should be `x <= n`. `x` is initialized to 1, so `x > n` will always be false and the loop will never run.
2. You should be using `<=` (less than or equal to) not `>`. If you don't use the "or equal to", then it won't run on the last time.

```js
let fact = 1;
let n = 5;
for (let x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
  fact *= (x)
}

console.log(fact)
```